# Authenticating with OpenLDAP from PHP

Tags: centos7, openldap, php-7.2

Using CentOS 7.5, Apache 2.4.6. Running in a VM. No SSL.

I followed https://linuxhostsupport.com/blog/how-to-install-ldap-on-centos-7/ and configured OpenLDAP.

From PHP, when I do an anonymous bind, and issue ldap_search, I see the entry for the user.

When binding with the userid & password, the function fails.

P.S: In case I am typing the wrong password, how do I change a password for a user defined in LDAP using ldif file?

Here is the code:

```
$ds = ldap_connect("localhost");  // must be a valid LDAP server!
echo "LDAP Server connection result is " . $ds . "<br />";

if ($ds) { 
  echo "Binding ..."; 
  $r=ldap_bind($ds);     // this is an "anonymous" bind, typically
                       // read-only access
echo "Bind result is " . $r . "<br />";

echo "Searching for (sn=*) ...";
// Search surname entry
$sr=ldap_search($ds, "o=Sapphire, ou=karachi", "sn=*");  
echo "Search result is " . $sr . "<br />";

echo "Number of entries returned is " . ldap_count_entries($ds, $sr) . "<br />";

echo "Getting entries ...<p>";
$info = ldap_get_entries($ds, $sr);
echo "Data for " . $info["count"] . " items returned:<p>";

for ($i=0; $i<$info["count"]; $i++) {
    echo "dn is: " . $info[$i]["dn"] . "<br />";
    echo "first cn entry is: " . $info[$i]["cn"][0] . "<br />";
    echo "first email entry is: " . $info[$i]["mail"][0] . "<br /><hr />";
}

echo "Binding as $userid ...  ";
if( $r = ldap_bind($ds, "uid=hussain,ou=People,dc=karachi,dc=sapphire", $password) ){
  echo "Userid or Password is valid";
}else{
  echo "Userid or Password is not valid";
}

echo "Closing connection";
ldap_close($ds);

} else {
  echo "<h4>Unable to connect to LDAP server</h4>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. I needed to add

```
ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
```

before issuing the bind.